# Tempo de execução de trecho de um código com precisão superior a 0.001 segundos

Tags: c++

Preciso computar o tempo de execução de algoritmos de ordenação. Fiz o seguinte:

```
steady_clock::time_point t3 = steady_clock::now();  
quickSort(v, 0, n - 1);  
steady_clock::time_point t4 = steady_clock::now();  
duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double,nano>>(t4 - t3);
```

O problema é que para tempo não consigo computar tempos inferiores a 0.001 segundos, o valor de `time_span` aparece igual a 0.

Comment: trocar `steady_clock` por `high_resolution_clock` resolve alguma coisa? Eu acho pouco provável, mas possível.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja na linha

```
duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double,nano>>(t4 - t3);
```

Você esqueceu de `std::nano` e baixou a resolução para segundos. Essa é a razão pela qual eu prefiro usar `auto` nesses casos. Experimente substituir por

```
  auto time_span = duration_cast<duration<double, nano>>(t4 - t3);
```

Comment: eu nao coloquei o nano para mostrar o resultado em segundos, mas para testar fiz do jeito que vc falou usando (auto) e ainda nao conseguir um tempo abaixo de 0.001 segundos